# unable to create metric in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am creating the metric alerts in azure through the below command.

```
Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule -Name dev -Location "west europe" -ResourceGroup XXXXXXXXXX -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/09ee41f7-af9d-4231-b369-0cd04262eda8/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs/abc" -MetricName "Throttled Requests" -TimeAggregationOperator Total
```

I am getting the below error.

> The metric with namespace '' and name 'Throttled Requests' is not
>   supported for this resource id
>   '/subscriptions/abc/resourceGroups/asdaddas/providers/Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs/xxxx'.,
>   Code: UnsupportedMetric, Status code:BadRequest,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule` creates `metric alert(classic)`, it does not support the resource `Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs`.

Reference - [Supported resource types for metric alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview#supported-resource-types-for-metric-alerts)

[image]

Besides, `metric alert(classic)` will be retired soon. I recommend you to look into the [new metric alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-near-real-time), it supports `Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs`. But you should note it also does not support the `Throttled Requests` metric, for supported metrics see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftdevicesiothubs).

If you want to use powershell, see this command - [`Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-2.5.0).

Comment: Does it mean that metric creation for IoT hub is not possible via script. The only way to create script is only through azure portal

Comment: @jubi It means `metric alert(classic)` does not support Iot hub, you could not create `metric alert(classic)` both in script or portal. You could create new metric alert via powrshell, portal, etc.

Comment: @jubi You should know the resource type of them. The `metric alert(classic)`, its resource type is `Microsoft.Insights/alertRules`. The new metric alert is `Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts`.

Comment: Will you be able to share me a sample script for creating throttled request alert on iot hub through script

Comment: @jubi I have mentioned it in my answer, the `Throttled Requests` metric is also not supported by the new metric, see the link in my answer for supported metrics type. In conclusion, there are two points. 1. metric alert(classic) does not support Iot hub, 2. you could just use new metric alert for Iot hub, but you could not use `Throttled Requests` metric. Juts event hub, service bus support the `Throttled Requests`, it is clear in the doc, and they are also preview now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on Throttled request. I will try with with totaldevices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197542/discussion-between-jubi-and-joy-wang).